# What does "Days of Future Past" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, future-time

What does [*X-Men: Days of Future Past*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Days_of_Future_Past) mean?

I interpret it to mean: days without future, where "past" on "future past" means gone. Is that so?

Comment: To the time traveller who has gone back in time, the days of the future are in their past. Or the days of the past are now in their future...

Answer (score 2):

The introduction to the Wikipedia article you linked gives enough context to determine the meaning: it is a reference to time travel, which is an important part of the plot. According to Wikipedia the title of the movie is the same as the title of the comic book the movie is based on; in turn the comic book is (supposedly) named for a musical album titled [*Days of Future Passed*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_of_Future_Passed).

*Days of Future Passed* is grammatical and makes some small amount of logical sense—it refers to days which, in the future, have passed. *Days of Future Past* is not quite as grammatical but carries the same general meaning. But really neither phrase makes very much sense—you would not use either one in everyday conversation—and that is okay. Artistic titles aren't always good English and don't always make sense.

Comment: nice answer. But i wonder if I could use this same phrase :"the days of the past" to mean days without outlook of future, of course giving the right context. So using the word "pass" to mean "no longer"